# Filter rows that have complete missings on specific set of columns r

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

Say I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(cntry = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C"),
                 year = c(2010, 2011, 2010, 2010, 2011),
                 env_1 = c(NA,NA,0,0,NA),
                 env_2 = c(NA,NA,1,1,0),
                 env_3 = c(NA,1,1,NA,0))
```

Which looks like:

```
cntry year env_1 env_2 env_3
A     2010    NA    NA    NA
A     2011    NA    NA     1
B     2010     0     1     1
C     2010     0     1    NA
C     2011    NA     0     0
```

I want to remove all rows that have complete missings on all substantive variables, in this case `env_1`, `env_2`, and `env_3`. How can I filter for those, while keeping the variables that have data in some, but missing in others?

I thought something like:

```
df %>% 
  filter(if_all(starts_with("env"), ~ !is.na(.x)))
```

But actually it should somehow be the opposite (this removes all rows with at least one NA)

I want to keep the following:

```
cntry year env_1 env_2 env_3
A     2011    NA    NA     1
B     2010     0     1     1
C     2010     0     1    NA
C     2011    NA     0     0
```

Comment: `df %>% filter(!if_all(starts_with("env"), ~ is.na(.x)))`

Comment: The answer was that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one (very probably not optimal) solution:

```
df <- data.frame(cntry = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C"),
                 year = c(2010, 2011, 2010, 2010, 2011),
                 env_1 = c(NA,NA,0,0,NA),
                 env_2 = c(NA,NA,1,1,0),
                 env_3 = c(NA,1,1,NA,0))

df[rowSums(is.na(df[c('env_1','env_2','env_3')])) != 3,]
```

output:

```
  cntry year env_1 env_2 env_3
2     A 2011    NA    NA     1
3     B 2010     0     1     1
4     C 2010     0     1    NA
5     C 2011    NA     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `complete.cases` with `if_any`, avoiding negation:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(if_any(starts_with("env"), complete.cases))
```